# How to automatically add parentheses and slashs in a form input?

Tags: php, html, xampp

So, i'm doing an form where i need to receive a phone number from the client, i want it to automatically add the parentheses and slashs to it(phone number in my country is (XX)XXXXX-XXXX) is there anyway i can do this using only html and php? without using javascript or jquery

sorry for my english

EDIT:the problem is, apparently the host that i'm using don't support javascript, this is a common thing or should i look for another host? or i just misunderstand and this lack of support is in the server side javascript and not on the client side?

```php
 <form class="form-signin" method="POST">
    ...
    <label for="inputNumber" class="sr-only">Phone number</label>
    <input type="text" name="number" id="inputNumber" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone number" required autofocus>
    ...
</form>
```

Comment: It’s unclear where you want the transformation to occur.  How are you going to store it?  If you are going to store it formatted, nothing needs to be done in the form; you would need to transform it as part of your data validation before you save it to database.  If, however, you store it without formatting, you need a decorator function to format as you present it in the form.

Comment: If you want to accept their input and show it formatted *before* it is submitted, then you **must** use client side language (JavaScript/JQuery)

Comment: if you need it formated on button click (pr any other trigger) you can do it with pure php, if you need it formated on the go (while typing) you can do it only by javascript.

Comment: Did you manage to get it working?

Answer (score 1):

You could split the string up using `substr` and then format it again using `sprintf`, for example:

```php
function formatPhone($number) {
    return sprintf(
        '(%s)%s-%s',
        substr($number, 0, 2),
        substr($number, 2, 5),
        substr($number, 7, 4)
    );
}

echo formatPhone('32949412293') // prints (32)94941-2293
```

Comment: I would suggest doing this as a function, which encourages reuse. I.e., `function as_phone($number) { ...)`

Comment: Agreed, I just posted a quick example of how it could be done. I'll update my answer.